# "webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest" returns NO. Good. But how can I redirect user to another view

Tags: ios, xcode, view

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
    {
       BOOL bLoadRequest = YES;

       if (this is the page you want to intercept)
       {
           bLoadRequest = NO;

           // Push your new scene.
       }

       return bLoadRequest;
    }
```

I simply want to represent another new view controller in storyboards if it returns NO.

But I can't figure it out.

Can someone please help me with this part, "// Push your new scene."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common practice to make your view controller also the delegate to your `UIWebView`. So assuming your view controller is inside a `UINavigationController`, you could push your new view with:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourNewViewController animated:YES];
```

or if you're not using a navigation controller:

```
[self presentViewController:yourNewViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: your guess is right, it is in the navigationcontroller. but I think my viewcontroller doesn't know about new viewcontroller! (like use od undeclared identifier 'myNewViewController'.....) How can I make it declared? I imported 'myNewViewController.h" But does nothing.

Comment: Well, I don't know it is right but I synthesized 'myNewViewController' to let my view controller recognize new view controller. It seems like OK. But I got this error on the runtime...."*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <LoginViewController: 0x6a73580>."